# Can I find wins and draws faster

Tags: c#, optimization

I have a time sensitive application where I get the rank of each object and work out who won or tied for first. With my current algorithm I get some lag in my program so am hoping to speed it up. In this demo version I just get a random number for the ranks as the real rank calc requires too much code to post.

Can anybody suggest how I might do this more quickly as the Update method can get called tens of thousands of times for a single run?

```
class Program
{
    static int runOuts = 0;
    static Dictionary<RankedObject, int> dictionaryWins = new Dictionary<RankedObject, int>();
    static Dictionary<RankedObject, int> dictionaryDraws = new Dictionary<RankedObject, int>();
    static Random random = new Random();
    static List<RankedObject> rankedObjects = new List<RankedObject>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // create some objects for demo
        rankedObjects.Add(new RankedObject());
        rankedObjects.Add(new RankedObject());
        rankedObjects.Add(new RankedObject());

        // add each object to the win/draw dictionaries so we can count wins/draws for each
        foreach (RankedObject rankedObj in rankedObjects)
        {
            dictionaryWins.Add(rankedObj, 0);
            dictionaryDraws.Add(rankedObj, 0);
        }

        // calculate wins/draws many times
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            Update();
        }
        

        // set equity results in each ranked combo and print results
        foreach (RankedObject rankedCombo in rankedObjects)
        {
            rankedCombo.WinEquity = dictionaryWins[rankedCombo] / (double)runOuts;
            rankedCombo.DrawEquity = dictionaryDraws[rankedCombo] / (double)runOuts;
            Console.WriteLine(rankedCombo);
        }
    }

    private static void Update()
    {
        // keep a list of ranks for each object so we can get max/winning value easily
        List<int> ranks = new List<int>();

        // get a rank for each object
        foreach (RankedObject rankedCombo in rankedObjects)
        {
            int rank = random.Next(3);
            ranks.Add(rank);
            rankedCombo.Rank = rank;
        }

        // get the maximum rank and how many times it occurs, so we know if their is a tie for the win
        int max = ranks.Max();
        int maxOccurences = 0;
        foreach (int i in ranks)
        {
            if (i == max)
            {
                maxOccurences++;
            }
        }

        // loop over each object to record if the object won or tied for win
        foreach (RankedObject rankedObj in rankedObjects)
        {
            if (rankedObj.Rank == max && maxOccurences == 1) // current rankedObj was winner
            {
                dictionaryWins[rankedObj] += 1;

            }
            else if (rankedObj.Rank == max && maxOccurences > 1) // current rankedObj Tied for win
            {
                dictionaryDraws[rankedObj] += 1;

            }
        }
        runOuts++;
    }
}


class RankedObject
{
    int rank;
    double winEquity;
    double drawEquity;

    public int Rank { get => rank; set => rank = value; }
    public double WinEquity { get => winEquity; set => winEquity = value; }
    public double DrawEquity { get => drawEquity; set => drawEquity = value; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Win Equity: " + winEquity + ", Draw Equity: " + drawEquity;
    }
}
```

Comment: foreach loops are much slower than for loops https://codingsight.com/foreach-or-for-that-is-the-question/ so i would start by replacing these

Comment: You don't need an array to identify the max & count how many times it occurs.

Comment: Is this `RankedObject` class an abbreviation? It's missing some things that are expected in a class that is used as a key in dictionary

Comment: RankedObject is an abbreviation but which items is it missing? The Dictionary seems to work fine.

Comment: Maybe this question is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @SteveW the hashcode override and equality test

Comment: @ScottHunter how can I check for Ties without counting occurences of max?

Comment: The first step in optimization is: measure and profile. How much time does the code take? And where is this time spent?

Comment: In your list, you don't need to retain all RankedObjects which you previously iterated through. Instead store only the few RankedObjects, which are the current max. When you find a new max rank, clear the list and add the new max object again.